# empty variables qlik view

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Why are my variables empty?

```
[SalesFunnel_DateParams_temp]:  
Load
  date(date#([dateto], 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as [datetonew],
  date(date#([datefrom], 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as [datefromnew];
SQL 
SELECT  
  *
FROM [BI_DWH_CORE].[Reporting].[v_QV_COM_SalesFunnel_DateParams];

let va = date(date#([dateto],'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DDMMYYYY');
let vb = date(date#([datefrom],'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DDMMYYYY');
let vblob = 'My name is blob!';
```

`let vblob` is fine. that was a test. The date variables contain nothing.

PS. the fields do return values in Qlik.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cant get field values like that. A field can contain more than one value. In this case you'll have to loop through the field values or get field value on specific position.

### Single (specific) value on position

If you want to get value from a field in specific position then you can use [peek](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm#) function.

```
let vA = peek('datetonew');
let vB = peek('datetonew', 1);
```

In the above example `vA` will return the last loaded value from `datetonew` field (`peek` is missing an optional position parameter).

For `vB` we explicitly stating that we want the 1st value from `datetonew` field.

### Loop through all values

If you still want to loop through all values in a field then you can use [For each ... next](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptControlStatements/For%20Each.htm) statement.

```
For Each i in FieldValueList('datetonew')
    trace $(i);
next
```

The script above will just print each **DISTINCT** value from `datetonew` field.